# Book about Benjamin Franklin in the modern day

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, government

This relatively short book (novella, maybe) may more properly be considered a political essay.  However, it does include bringing Benjamin Franklin forward in time to explain the reasons for why portions of the government and law are set up as they are.

I believe the location of the story was Washington DC.

I think I read this in the early 90's.  It did include an ATM, so it was likely written in the 80's at the earliest.

One point I remember is Benjamin Franklin being amazed at ATMs creating money.  This was not further developed, and I remember thinking that Benjamin Franklin would actually be horrified at "free money".

I believe the major thrust of the book was that the main character was attempting to put through a law or amendment that would allow for holders of federal office to face a recall election.  I think the focus was on Representatives and Senators, but possibly also included the President.

I believe Benjamin's argument was that this would bog down the government and that the office holders would essentially be continuously running for reelection and would be unable to accomplish anything.

Comment: I have found one book "Ben Franklin and the Chamber of Time" that was published in the mid-nineties by an author that has written other books I read about the same time (Chris Heimerdinger).  However, the descriptions of it have it more of a YA fantasy adventure.  It also sounds like it was Franklin's invention that brought him forward in time while I think it was something built in the present day.   I would have to get a copy or preview of the book to say one way or another.